# Pivot selectionChanged Event and click handlers in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, blend

I don't want to put my click handlers in APP.XAML.CS, so I want left them in pivot.XAML. and pivot.XAML.CS

How can I do that?

```
   private void Pivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           // MessageBox.Show("Pivot selection changed");
            switch (((Pivot)sender).SelectedIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                   // MessageBox.Show("LoginAppBar launched");
                    ApplicationBar = ((ApplicationBar)Application.Current.Resources["zero"]);
                    break;

                case 1:
                   // MessageBox.Show("DefaultAppBar launched");
                    ApplicationBar = ((ApplicationBar)Application.Current.Resources["one"]);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    //Console.WriteLine("DefaultAppBar launched");
                    ApplicationBar = ((ApplicationBar)Application.Current.Resources["two"]);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //Console.WriteLine("DefaultAppBar launched");
                    ApplicationBar = ((ApplicationBar)Application.Current.Resources["three"]);
                    break;    
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your pivot is in App.xaml page? Can you give little more details like where is the Pivot control etc?

Comment: no, pivot is in the mainpage.xaml, but when i want to put 4 application bars for 4 cases of pivot items, it searches click handlers from app.xaml.cs itself. but click handlers are in mainpage.xaml, btw i have used MSDN tutorial for addind extra bars, b ut i cant control click handlers on the application bar http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394036(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: you can declare the application bar in main.xaml itself with some name and when pivot items are changed then you can bind the click items to button and unbind the rest of click items right

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the click events as described in the MSDN link by attaching application bar of respective pivot. And you can add or remove button to application bar like this

```
ApplicationBarIconButton button1 = new ApplicationBarIconButton();
button1.IconUri = new Uri("/Images/icon_search.png", UriKind.Relative);
button1.Text = "Search";
ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(button1); // adding button
button1.Click -= ShowSearch; // Adding event to button
button1.Click += ShowSearch;

//Removing second button
ApplicationBar.Buttons.Remove(ApplicationBar.Buttons[1] as ApplicationBarIconButton);
```

Still if you have problem with click events like for example you have search feature in each pivot and you want to bind the search event handler. For that you can bind one event and inside the event you can search the Values based on the current Pivot selected

```
private void ShowSearch(object sender, EventArgs e)// event in the application bar button
{
   if (NameOfPivot.SelectedIndex == 0)
   {
     // Do your action here
   }
   else if (NameOfPivot.SelectedIndex == 1)
   {
     // Do your action here
   }
   else if (NameOfPivot.SelectedIndex == 2)
   {
     // Do your action here
   }
}
```